# True or false? The three points $(1,2,0), (1,1,1)$ and $(0,0,-1)$ lie in the same plane in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, vectors

True or false? The three points $(1,2,0), (1,1,1)$ and $(0,0,-1)$ lie in the same plane in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$

I think an equivalent question would be if these vectors are linearly dependent?

So I made this in matrix form and used sarrus rule to calculate the determinant.

$$\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0\\ 
2 & 1 & 0\\ 
0 & 1 & -1
\end{vmatrix}\left.\begin{matrix}
1 & 1 & \\ 
2 & 1 & \\ 
0 & 1 & 
\end{matrix}\right|$$

And the determinant is $-1$ and thus the statement is false.

Did I do it correctly? Please tell me, I'm preparing for an exam.

Comment: Three (different) points *always* lie in a common  plane.

Comment: @MartinR even stronger, we can of course say that three distinct points *define* a place in $\mathbb{R}^3$... OP, What is your definition of a plane?

Comment: @MartinR: they don't even need to be different.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Being distinct is not sufficient.  Consider three points on a line.  They don't define a unique plane.

Comment: @BobbieD ah, you're right. Forgot to explicitly write that condition. OK, so three distinct and not-colinear points in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing you did wrong is that, considering these points as vectors you add the starting point $(0,0,0)$, so you try to see that these points and the point $(0,0,0)$ is on the same plane or not. And your result shows that they are not. You may choose one point as a starting point, then you have 2 vectors, which must lie in a plane.
In general, if you have more than 3 points, you may choose one of them, say A, as a starting point, then calculate the vectors starting with A and ending with each of other points, then see if these vectors belong to the same plane or not.